# UnknownObjectException at /github/ 404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository

Tags: python, github, github-api, github-api-v3, github-api-v4

I want to create the webhook of  the repository as a GitHub webhook.

It is done if I create manually in GitHub repo setting webhook, and it works properly.
But if I use the API key, this does not work. It gives me error like this

```
#in django:
UnknownObjectException at /github/
404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-webhook"}
```

```
#in api key:

    {
        "message": "Not Found",
        "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-webhook"
    }
```

```
#when i use the pygithub library this given and error     
  

      ENDPOINT = 'github'
        HOST = '4c3a-2402-8100-2120-eed5-a954-5f2d-6cf3-7134.in.ngrok.io'
        EVENTS = ["push", "pull_request"]
        config = {
        "url": f"https://{HOST}/{ENDPOINT}",
        "content_type": "json"
        }
        g=Github('access_token')
        repo = g.get_repo("OneSakib/" + 'blog')
        res = repo.create_hook(name="web", config=config, events=EVENTS, active=True)
```

If I use directly the GitHub API again, it give same error.
What should I do, please?

```
# this is curl 

    curl "https://api.github.com/repos/onesakib/blog/hooks" -H "Authorization: Token my-access-token" -d '{"name":"web", "active":true,"events":["push"],"config":{"url":"https://4c3a-2402-8100-2120-eed5-a954-5f2d-6cf3-7134.in.ngrok.io/webhook","content_type":"json"}}'
```

If I use postman, then it gives the same error.
Please tell me what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

> if i use api key

When you [generate a new token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), make sure to [set the scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) to `repo` in order to access the repo webhook.

Test it first with [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api), with

```bash
gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  repos/OWNER/REPO/hooks
  -f name=web -f config=config -f events=EVENTS -f active=True
```

Comment: Thanku so much sir this is work, this problem came for the scope , beacause i give not permission.

Comment: @SakibMalik Great, well done!